# Creating JSON object using string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Say I have this code in node.js:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var file_content = fs.readFileSync('file.json');
var json = JSON.parse(file_content);

let x = "c";
json.x = 3;
fs.writeFileSync("file.json", JSON.stringify(json));
```

and this JSON file:

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

I want to create json object `"c"` but this code would create `"x"`. How would I create `"c"` *this way?*

Comment: ```json.c = 3?```

Comment: JSON is string data. You don't create JSON objects, that's not a thing, you simply create a normal JS object, and then you turn _that_ into a JSON string. So just set a property called `c` in the exact same way you're currently setting a property called `x`. Done.

Comment: Does documentation even exist anymore?

Comment: you can use `json.c = 3;` or `json['c'] = 3;`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the property `c` of the object json. The synthax `json.x` corresponds to the property `x`. You need to use square brackets if you want the value of x as property.

```js
let x = 'c';
json[x] = 3;
```